# Where does the monster go after getting murdered in Purgatory?

Tags: supernatural

And I quote "If you murder a monster in  monster heaven where does it go?"
- Castiel, Supernatural Season 8 Episode 5

Vampires, Leviathans, werewolves etc. suffer in Purgatory after getting murdered on Earth. When Dean went to purgatory he murdered many Purgatory "natives". So where does those purgatory creatures go?

Comment: When Dean goes into purgatory with a vampire, that's a reference to Skyrim, when your character goes into the soul cairn, where lost souls go, mainly souls of monsters in the game.

Comment: I think the Soul Cairn is mostly the souls of soul-trapped people and animals.

Comment: But it is a huge reference, because in the game, you go into the soul cairn with a vampire, just like in supernatural.

Comment: Maybe so. Dawnguard came out a few months before season 8 of Supernatural, so it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### OFFICIAL STATUS: It is unconfirmed what happens to the souls of monsters once consigned to Purgatory if they are killed IN Purgatory.

- Supernatural has never given an official answer as to whether the souls of those consigned to Purgatory are indestructible and thus while able to be killed will somehow return to their semblance of their corporeal existence.

> Purgatory is a realm where the souls of supernatural creatures go after they die. Its physical location is separate from both Heaven and Hell. Crowley estimates there are 30-40 million souls there. It was originally created by God to contain the oldest creatures, leviathans, for fear they would destroy the rest of creation.

- [Purgatory](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Purgatory) was designed as a prison dimension filled with the immortal essences of monsters. While Purgatory may have been created initially to hold [Leviathans](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Leviathans), it is now also the spiritual repository of all monsters upon death.
- A monster's soul is destined for Purgatory and once there, cannot leave except under very special circumstances. Monsters have a relationship to Purgatory through their connection to the Mother of All Monsters, Eve. Purgatory, for a time was even a third player in the War between Heaven and Hell.
- Purgatory, unlike Heaven or Hell appears as a physical realm with an overcast sky or an occasional night. While it appears as an infinite plane of existence, it appears to have certain landmarks usable as reference points in relation to portals of entry or exit.
- Matter in Purgatory can be sculpted to make weapons enhancing one's fighting ability and can be taken from Purgatory to Earth. Dean still has a knife he made there.
- While the bodies there appear to be cloaked in flesh when they are killed in conflict since they cannot leave, it is suspected they are essentially reborn or renewed sometime later, possible at a different location.**
- While this may appear, at first, to mean no one ever stays dead, it could have other unpleasant side effects, the most important of them being, if you are weak, you spend a whole lot of time dying or moving.

> Every soul here is a monster. This is where they come to prey upon each other for all eternity.
>
> – Castiel, 7.23 "Survival of the Fittest"

Answer (score 4):

This was somewhere in an earlier season, when Purgatory was first being described.  Monsters killed in Purgatory reappear back in Purgatory at some point, killing each other over and over again.  I think it was Crowley who described it as such.

However, this was prior to gaining access to it, so we can't be *completely* certain that this was a correct description.

Answer (score -1):

I like to think that they just go to the empty along with angels and demons. Making somewhat of a pit stop on the way to the final destination.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. A good answer shouldn't be just a fan theory or preference though. It should be grounded in evidence from an official source.